# PRISMA query for date in Node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

So I'm having trouble in query with Prisma. In my db, data stored in this format in Postgres:

```
 [
    {
    "name":"xyz",
    "last_time_to_active":"2022-09-12 21:49:44.712811+05" // Timestamptz datatype in DB
    },
    {
    "name":"abc",
    "last_time_to_active":"2022-09-13 16:49:44.712811+05" // Timestamptz datatype in DB
    },
    {
    "name":"bcd",
    "last_time_to_active":"2022-09-11 17:49:44.712811+05" // Timestamptz datatype in DB
    }
    ]
```

This is my query:

```
await prisma.user.findMany({
      where: {
        //Now I want to find data on the basis of date only which "2022-09-10", etc.
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare this column to `Date` objects. If you want to get all timestamps on a certain day (here: `2022-09-10`), that should do the trick:

```js
prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    lastTimeToActive: { 
      gte: new Date("2022-09-10"), 
      lt: new Date("2020-09-11") 
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Actually what if I have lots of data with different dates like throughout date of the year. I tried this it didn't worked, because I want exact data against that `date` only, excluding `time`. I even tried this by `equals`, but no luck.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the issue? Lots of data in the database? Lots of dates in the `where` condition? What exactly did you try? And how did it not work?

Comment: Actually in my database data is stored, in a format I've mentioned above i.e sample data.
So what I want is to find Data only the basis of date only i.e `2022-09-12` instead of `2022-09-12 21:49:44.712811+05` in findMany `query`.
For example: **I've pass date in query which is  `2022-09-12` (or any other date), it should return all the data against that date, rather than passing date with time in query.**

Comment: That's understood. It tried to provide a solution that shows you, how to do that for `2022-09-10`. If you want `2022-09-12` instead, you would have to update it accordingly.

Comment: but when I try to execute this it returns me nothing. For this date or any other

Comment: And the corresponding SQL statement would find matching rows?

Comment: It worked with SQL statement the other day, but not in prisma